# N+1 query - bullet remove includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using devise invitable to invite users to my application. As of now Bullet complains on removing includes on invited_by, which is used by the Gem I suppose.

```
POST /api/v1/users/invitation
AVOID eager loading detected
User => [:invited_by]
Remove from your finder: :includes => [:invited_by]
```

Is there a way to un_include this in Rails? For now I have disabled bullet in this section, but without that, how can I get past this error?

Comment: Do you use `default_scope` in `user` model?

Comment: No, I don't have any scopes defined in my user model.